# Getting a Dynamic Element by Selector

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, puppeteer

I need to click to a certain web button with the `id`: `#product-6852370-Size`.

I am working with Puppeteer, so normally I would do:

```
page.click('#product-6852370-Size');
```

The tricky part is that the number `6852370` is dynamic and changes every time I refresh the page.

So what I need is a piece of code that is saying:

Search for `id`'s that include `product-` and `-size`. Any way that this might happen?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can match the beginning and end of the `id` attribute using:

```
await page.click('[id^="product-"][id$="-Size"]');
```

Or, more accurately, you can ensure that a number is present in the middle of your `id` using regex:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="product-"][id$="-Size"]')].filter(e => e.id.match(/^product-\d+-Size$/g))[0].click();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use attribute starts with selector to do that:

```
page.click('button[id^="product-"]')
```